# Angular - Routing is not working (MEAN)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes, mean-stack

I'm working on my first Angular app and I have a problem with routing, because app response with "Cannot GET /(url)" errors. Console logs are empty, so after reading many similar topics I suspect issue with server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var api = require('./server/api.js');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use('/', api);

app.get('*'), (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
}

var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log("Server is running"));
```

In my index.html I have:

```
<base href="/">
```

so this is not source of the problem. Angular routing code is good, I've tested it on other app. I would grateful for some help.

app-routing.module:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {RouterModule, Route} from "@angular/router";
import {Pgee2017StatsComponent} from "./pgee2017/pgee2017-stats/pgee2017-stats.component";

const APP_ROUTES : Route[] = [
    { path: 'pgee17', component: Pgee2017StatsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)
    ],
    exports: [
    RouterModule
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: server code is near perfect. Need more info on what route you are calling, please also check network call tab in developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I added code from app-routing.module. AppRoutingModule is imported in app,module. When i go to http://localhost:3000/pgee17 i receive "Cannot GET /pgee17". Augury says that "This application is not an Angular application. This application cannot be inspected using Augury.", network is also empty.

Comment: did you try running it with ng serve instead of having express serve it?

Comment: Yes, but in this case I have no data from my mongodb:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
core.js:1448 ERROR Response