# Angular route is not working in Combined MEAN?

Tags: node.js, express

I created a single page app using Angular.I'm using Node/Express on the back-end. While Express is serving my static index.html correctly.
When i try to navigation to some angular route from url address bar it saying cannot get /login...

i found this question on stackoverflow it is exactly what i am saying but its not answered yet.
[Angular - Routing is not working (MEAN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844931/angular-routing-is-not-working-mean)

Here is my code.

```
var path = require("path");

var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var app = express();

require('./startups/prod')(app);

// Temp.
const TempRoutes = require("./routes/temp");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/node-angular', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to database.");
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("Connection Failed.");
    });

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));

app.use((request, response, next) => {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requesed-With, Content-Type, Accept,Accept-Language,Content-Language, Authorization");
    response.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});


app.use((request, response, next) => {
    response.sendFile(__dirname, path.join("dist", "index.html"))
})

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: If this is relevant to Angular, please add the Angular code, otherwise remove the Angular tag

Comment: @KurtHamilton Ok...